# Replace values in a series exceeding a threshold

Tags: r

In a dataframe I'd like to replace values in a series where they exceed a given threshold.

For example, within a group ('ID') in a series designated by 'time',  if 'value' ever exceeds 3, I'd like to make all following entries also equal 3.

```
ID <- as.factor(c(rep("A", 3), rep("B",3), rep("C",3)))
time <- rep(1:3, 3)
value <- c(c(1,1,2), c(2,3,2), c(3,3,2))
dat <- cbind.data.frame(ID, time, value)
dat

ID time value
A    1     1
A    2     1
A    3     2
B    1     2
B    2     3
B    3     2
C    1     3
C    2     3
C    3     2
```

I'd like it to be:

```
ID time value
A    1     1
A    2     1
A    3     2
B    1     2
B    2     3
B    3     3
C    1     3
C    2     3
C    3     3
```

This should be easy, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Another way to do this (using `cummax`) mentioned by @MrFlick is to use `data.table` package `library(data.table);
setDT(dat)[, value:= ifelse(cummax(value)> = 3, 3, value), ID];
dat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ave` function makes this very easy by allowing you to apply a function to each of the groupings. In this case, we will adapth the `cummax` (cumulative maximum) to see if we've seen a 3 yet.

```
dat$value2<-with(dat, ave(value, ID, FUN=
    function(x) ifelse(cummax(x)>=3, 3, x)))
dat;

#   ID time value value2
# 1  A    1     1      1
# 2  A    2     1      1
# 3  A    3     2      2
# 4  B    1     2      2
# 5  B    2     3      3
# 6  B    3     2      3
# 7  C    1     3      3
# 8  C    2     3      3
# 9  C    3     2      3
```

You could also just use `FUN=cummax` if you want never-decreasing values. I wasn't sure about the sequence `c(1,2,1)` if you wanted to keep that unchanged or not.

Comment: Hi again @MrFlick, what if i have another column name SubID for the data frame dat. i wanna do sth like ave(value, c(ID, SubID, FUN=...)) but it failed. how can i apply function with grouping based on two columns instead of one? Thanks!

Comment: @BeginneR (nice name, by the way) you _could_ do that for example by using the `dplyr` package in combination with the `ifelse` as proposed by MrFlick. It will let you group by any number of variables

Comment: XD @beginneR, i will take a look for 'dplyr' package. You seems not a beginner user of R anymore.

Comment: The syntax you want is `ave(value, ID, SubID, FUN=...)`

Comment: @BeginneR You can pass any number of grouping variables to `ave` as Michael said.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume your data are sorted by group, then this should be fast, essentially relying on findInterval() behind the scenes:

```
library(IRanges)
id <- Rle(ID)
three <- which(value>=3L)
ir <- reduce(IRanges(three, end(id)[findRun(three, id)])))
dat$value[as.integer(ir)] <- 3L
```

This avoids looping over the groups.